# Internet Explorer 11 converts border to currentColor

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, inline-styles

I have the simple html. It has the script at the bottom that shows style attribute values from the input text box.

As you can see the style of the input control has following properties: "border-top: medium none; border-right: medium none; border-bottom: medium none; border-left: medium none". However if you open this html file in IE 11, the script shows following: "border:currentColor". Not sure why? Please share your thoughts. I would like to alert the original properties from HTML.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form>
<input  style='border-top: medium none; border-right: medium none; border-bottom: medium none; border-left: medium none' readOnly size="1" value="Right" name="inputid" id="inputid"/>
<script language="JavaScript">
alert(document.getElementById("inputid").getAttribute("style"));
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: That's actually pretty funny. It seems IE is rewriting the style attribute based on the computed styles, which is exacerbated when you specify the initial values for all your borders (`medium none`). You can also see this rewritten attribute value when you inspect the element in F12 developer tools.

Comment: wait a sec.... is this a question BoltClock does not have an answer to?

Comment: Thanks BoltClock. You are right. My concern is:

I have a tool that converts my html into pdf format. Somehow the tool cannot understand "border:currentColor" and due to which it shows border for input element in the PDF. So I have to somehow stop IE11 by doing that conversion. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: when I try it, it renders in quirks mode. Try to add a document header and validate the html (type attribute in script tag, etc...).
it might be by design actually. if the inline style matches the default style, IE will not bother to set the runtime style any different from the inherited style (prove by leaving just the style for e.g. the top border in, it will be all different...)

Comment: does your tool generate the PDF by walking the DOM that IE generates from your HTML?

Comment: I send entire HTML to my tool.

Comment: so how it is an issue? if the converter tool interprets the HTML independently from IE, the observed style rewrite inside the IE engine does not apply IMO.

Comment: Converter tool fails to understand observed style rewrite. It can understand "border-top: medium none; border-right: medium none; border-bottom: medium none; border-left: medium none" but not "border:currentColor".